# CSS: Using raw svg in the URL parameter of a background-image in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, svg

So, I'm trying to do something like this:

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100px 100px;
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' style='fill:red; stroke:none'><rect x='0' y='40' width='100' height='20' /><rect x='40' y='0' width='20' height='100' /></svg>");
}
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/trxkcx41/4/

This works beautifully in current versions Chrome, Safari (OS X and iOS), and Firefox. However, the SVG doesn't appear at all in IE 9, 10, or 11.

Is that because this is not supported in IE, or because I'm doing something wrong?

***[UPDATE WITH SOLUTION]***

Thanks to [hungerstar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/804867/hungerstar), I've got this working. To summarize his recommendation, I needed to make the following changes:

1. Change the data type from `data:image/svg+xml;utf8` to `data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8` (i.e., `charset=` is required)
2. URL encode the svg. To minimize the URL-encoding, use `'` instead of `"` to enclose the attributes. So, in my case, only the `<` and `>` needed to be encoded.

To, ultimately, my CSS looked like this:

```
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' style='fill:red; stroke:none' %3E%3Crect x='0' y='40' width='100' height='20' /%3E%3Crect x='40' y='0' width='20' height='100' /%3E%3C/svg%3E");
```

Comment: Try [svg4everbody](https://github.com/jonathantneal/svg4everybody).

Comment: @hungerstar - thanks for the link; that's a cool tool! However, I'm really just trying to figure out whether IE supports this usage of SVG, and if so, what I'm doing wrong in my example.

Comment: I've successfully used base-64 in a data uri, [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pf4yw07v/).

Comment: I believe [this is the answer](http://codepen.io/Tigt/blog/optimizing-svgs-in-data-uris) you're looking for.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

IE does appear to support using `utf8` in a data URI, it's simply being more *fussy* about it. See this [Codepen Blog Post](http://codepen.io/Tigt/blog/optimizing-svgs-in-data-uris) for more details but here are the highlights:

The author points to [RFC2397](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2397.txt) and highlights:

> data:[<mediatype>][;base64],<data>
>
> The <mediatype> is an Internet media type specification (with optional parameters.) The appearance of ";base64" means that the data is encoded as base64. Without ";base64", the data (as a sequence of octets) is represented using ASCII encoding for octets inside the range of safe URL characters and using the standard %xx hex encoding of URLs for octets outside that range. If <mediatype> is omitted, it defaults to text/plain;charset=US-ASCII. As a shorthand, "text/plain" can be omitted but the charset parameter supplied.

- Most browsers are lenient about the charset= string, but it's required for Internet Explorer. That means you need to use `;charset=utf8,` instead of `;utf8,`.
- From above, *"Without ";base64", the data (as a sequence of octets) is represented using ASCII encoding for octets inside the range of safe URL characters and using the standard %xx hex encoding of URLs for octets outside that range."* Which means you will have to percent-encode characters that aren't URL-safe. For example, `<svg>` to `%3Csvg%3E`. You can minimize the amount of percent encoding that needs to be done by using single quotes `'` instead of double quotes `"`.

Comment: you can also omit `;charset=utf8` completely, assuming you don't use special characters in your svg file

Answer (score 19):

For **IE9** I have to **URL encode the whole SVG code**.

This is my workflow for SVG background images.

First paste SVG code here to optimize it:
https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/ ("paste markup")

You can remove the "viewBox" but be sure that "width" and "height" are defined in the SVG code, IE9 needs this for better CSS implementation.

Now you have something like:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="100"><path d="M0 0h100L50 50"/></svg>
```

In this case I have to add a fill color, because there was none defined. so I add:

```
fill="#cc0000"
```

to the end of the **path** element (if there are a couple of path elements in a group ("g") you have to put this fill color to all of these. If the SVG has strokes do the same with the strokes like `stroke="#cc0000"`).

Now we have the following SVG code:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="100"><path d="M0 0h100L50 50" fill="#cc0000"/></svg>
```

Now encode the whole SVG code here: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/

so you get:

```
%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20width%3D%22100%22%20height%3D%22100%22%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D%22M0%200h100L50%2050%22%20fill%3D%22%23cc0000%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E
```

At least put this whole thing together in your CSS:

```
.apple {
    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20width%3D%22100%22%20height%3D%22100%22%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D%22M0%200h100L50%2050%22%20fill%3D%22%23cc0000%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E');
    }
```

Some advantages that drove me nuts:

**Be sure** to wrap the SVG background code with `'` in the CSS because inside the SVG we use `"`!

**Be sure** to use

```
data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8
```

nothing else.

Now the SVG is displayed with the color "#cc0000" (dark red) even in IE9 on windows.

With this URL encoded SVG I still can change the color with a PHP variable. For example I just replace "cc0000" with:

```
<?php echo preg_replace("/#/", "", $textcolor); ?>
```

I do this for WordPress templates so the customer can pick the icon color in the backend.

[image]

Comment: This worked for me, although I found that I had to be patient and make sure that my code was correct and matched above. Slight variations resulted in the image not showing. If you are having trouble persevere!!

Comment: If you're using SCSS/Sass, here is a helpful function you can use to convert all the required characters: https://gist.github.com/JacobDB/0ffffaf8e772c12acf7102edb8a302be

Answer (score 0):

Just a note to this. In IE 11 you can use charset=utf8. You have to URL-encode at least `<` and `>` (providing that you use `''` for attribute values not `""`. Also, be careful in case you use any non-ASCII characters. You have to provide their UTF-8 encoded value - i.e. find some tool that gives you UTF-8 code for the character (like Babel Map) and then provide it in URL encoded form. i.e. I wanted to render the `▾` character (`U+25BE`). UTF-8 representation of the character is `\xE2\x96\xBE` and `%E2%96%BE` in URL-encoded form.

```
background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' version='1.1' height='10px' width='15px'%3E%3Ctext x='0' y='10' fill='gray'%3E%E2%96%BE%3C/text%3E%3C/svg%3E");
```

Answer (score -1):

This solution works well for me, I use the charset=utf8 to instead of utf8.