# SVG background-image not appearing on IE11

Tags: svg, internet-explorer-11

https://codepen.io/leftynaut/pen/PKwEqz

Any idea what I am doing wrong with my svg background image here to make them not show up on IE11?

(jQuery acting up on IE also, but my actual implementation with Angular is working fine)

`background: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 400 400'><path fill='#000000' d='M192,32 C103.75,32 32,103.75 32,192 C32,280.25 103.75,352 192,352 C280.25,352 352,280.25 352,192 C352,103.75 280.25,32 192,32 Z M384,192 C384,298 298,384 192,384 C86,384 0,298 0,192 C0,86 86,0 192,0 L192,0 C298,0 384,86 384,192 Z'></path></svg>") no-repeat center;`

Comment: Tried that, doesn't seem to have any effect other than blowing up the size on non-IE platforms.

Comment: Can't get that to work. Base64 works, although.

Answer (score 1):

I recently discovered that Internet Explorer is a bit picky with the format of the URL in background-image property. Specifically, you need to specify the charset differently and URL encode the SVG part:

```
background: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%27http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%27%20viewBox%3D%270%200%20400%20400%27%3E%3Cpath%20fill%3D%27%23000000%27%20d%3D%27M192%2C32%20C103.75%2C32%2032%2C103.75%2032%2C192%20C32%2C280.25%20103.75%2C352%20192%2C352%20C280.25%2C352%20352%2C280.25%20352%2C192%20C352%2C103.75%20280.25%2C32%20192%2C32%20Z%20M384%2C192%20C384%2C298%20298%2C384%20192%2C384%20C86%2C384%200%2C298%200%2C192%20C0%2C86%2086%2C0%20192%2C0%20L192%2C0%20C298%2C0%20384%2C86%20384%2C192%20Z%27%3E%3C%2Fpath%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E") no-repeat center;
```

For the record, the full URL encoding is probably overkill. You really only need to do the < and > but I'm just being lazy and using a URL encoder instead of editing your code directly.

It is discussed in greater detail over in this question:
[CSS: Using raw svg in the URL parameter of a background-image in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32870788/css-using-raw-svg-in-the-url-parameter-of-a-background-image-in-ie/32871853)

This CodePen shows the differences between implementations of inline SVG with the different charset, URL encode and Base64 encode: https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/zEJtC

Comment: Yes IE is very strict, this one works well:
url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='18' height='18' viewBox='0 0 24 24'%3E%3Cpath fill='%23666' d='M12 2C6.47 2 2 6.47 2 12s4.47 10 10 10 10-4.47 10-10S17.53 2 12 2zm5 13.59L15.59 17 12 13.41 8.41 17 7 15.59 10.59 12 7 8.41 8.41 7 12 10.59 15.59 7 17 8.41 13.41 12 17 15.59z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E")