# How do I use color code in inline svgs (google maps)

Tags: google-maps, svg, google-maps-api-3, inline-svg

I am displaying a custom marker as .svg in google maps API in JavaScript.

It seems like that the google maps api does not like using `#00492C` in code. `fill="#0000"` does not work, only `fill="green"` would work.

```
var icon: {
        url: 'data:image/svg+xml;utf-8, \
              <svg width="30" height="48" viewBox="1 -10 60 78" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"> \
              <path fill="#00492C" d="M53.1,48.1c3.9-5.1,6.3-11.3,6.3-18.2C59.4,13.7,46.2,0.5,30,0.5C13.8,0.5,0.6,13.7,0.6,29.9 c0,6.9,2.5,13.1,6.3,18.2C12.8,55.8,30,77.5,30,77.5S47.2,55.8,53.1,48.1z"></path> \
              </svg>'
    }
```

I am expecting my marker getting dark green but instead it just does not appear anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the # character as that's reserved for the [start of a fragment identifier in a URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier). Replace all occurances of # with %23

```
icon: {
    url: 'data:image/svg+xml;utf-8, \
          <svg width="30" height="48" viewBox="1 -10 60 78" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"> \
          <path fill="%2300492C" d="M53.1,48.1c3.9-5.1,6.3-11.3,6.3-18.2C59.4,13.7,46.2,0.5,30,0.5C13.8,0.5,0.6,13.7,0.6,29.9 c0,6.9,2.5,13.1,6.3,18.2C12.8,55.8,30,77.5,30,77.5S47.2,55.8,53.1,48.1z"></path> \
          </svg>'
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/0mq1zf86/3/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: {
      lat: -33,
      lng: 151
    }
  });
  var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {
      lat: -33.890,
      lng: 151.274
    },
    map: map,
    icon: {
      url: 'data:image/svg+xml;utf-8, \
              <svg width="30" height="48" viewBox="1 -10 60 78" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"> \
              <path fill="%2300492C" d="M53.1,48.1c3.9-5.1,6.3-11.3,6.3-18.2C59.4,13.7,46.2,0.5,30,0.5C13.8,0.5,0.6,13.7,0.6,29.9 c0,6.9,2.5,13.1,6.3,18.2C12.8,55.8,30,77.5,30,77.5S47.2,55.8,53.1,48.1z"></path> \
              </svg>'
    }
  });
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Comment: I realized that this does not work on Internet Explorer. Do you have a solution for this?

Comment: There are Internet Explorer questions about such things here already such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32870788/css-using-raw-svg-in-the-url-parameter-of-a-background-image-in-ie) if that doesn't help you can surely find others that will.